# Windows 7 Aero effects disabled after safe-mode booting

Tags: windows-7, aero

Last week I started my Windows 7 laptop in safe-mode. Since then, even if it boots normally, the Aero effects are disabled. It comes back after running the Aero troubleshooter. The diagnostic message displayed is:

```
Desktop Window Manager is disabled            Detected
The current theme doesn't support Aero        Fixed
```

How can I make Aero work without running the troubleshooter every time I login?

Answer (score 0):

**Force Enable Aero in Windows 7:**

1. Click on Start and type regedit at run
2. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
   ```
3. In the right details pane, create following Three DWORD (32-bit value) entry

   - UseMachineCheck, and set its value to 0.
   - Blur, and set its value to 0.
   - Animations, and set its value to 0.
4. Close Regedit
5. Click on Start and type CMD with administrative Priviliges
6. Now type the following commands:

   ```
   Net Stop uxsms  
   Net Start uxsms
   ```

   The above commands will stop and start the Desktop Window Manager Session Manager.
7. Now you can turn on Aero by right clicking on desktop-> Personalize -> Select Windows Colors